# User.GetUserId() fails inside controller's constructor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am getting the following error: **Value cannot be null. Parameter name: principal**

How can I access Identity (userId) inside the controller's constructor? I can only get it working by wrapping the failed call in a function (both highlighted below).

Is there anything I need to inject?

```
public class BaseController : Controller {
    protected readonly MylDbContext dbContext;
    protected readonly string userId;

    public BaseController(MylDbContext dbContext) {
        this.dbContext = dbContext;
        userId = User.GetUserId(); // fails here
    }

    public string GetUserId() {
        return User.GetUserId(); // works here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As @Henk mentioned, the controller constructor will be executed before the ActionContext has been set, so you won't have access to properties like `Context`, `Request` or `User`. You need to retrieve the userId within the context of a request.

You could use the old-fashioned approach of the [action filters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381609(v=vs.100).aspx) which are still part of the MVC6 pipeline (Which also supports async action filters via `IAsyncActionFilter`).

Since you want to set a property in your controller, the most simple way you could implement this is by overriding the `OnActionExecuting` method in your controller class. This works because you are inheriting from [`Controller`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ViewFeatures/Controller.cs), which already implements `IActionFilter`.

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
{
    //Get user id   
    userId = User.GetUserId();
}
```

**Edit**

If you check the [`DefaultControllerFactory`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/eef6c3883a7e27b8387b0925f0b6a88df0a484c5/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core/Controllers/DefaultControllerFactory.cs) you will see that:

1. first the controller is created
2. then the ActionContext is set (Via the [`DefaultControllerPropertyActivator`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/9342cb0ab78add8c527edcbc4c0988edc96f01e3/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core/Controllers/DefaultControllerPropertyActivator.cs) which is one of the property activators):

   ```
   var controller = _controllerActivator.Create(actionContext, controllerType);
   foreach (var propertyActivator in _propertyActivators)
   {
       propertyActivator.Activate(actionContext, controller);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

When the controller is instantiated there is no guarantee that the request information is avaiable in the HttpContext yet. There might not be a request at all. Is there reason why you need that information in the constructor?

**Edit**
I understand your issue. What I usually do in a scenario like this, is create a property with a backing field which only queries once per controller:

```
private int? _userId;
public int UserId
{
    get
    {
        if (!_userId.HasValue)
        {
            // query from db.
            _userId = 42;
        }
        return _userId.Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Yes, I want all my API controllers to inherit from this so called 'BaseController'. Will be using that userId to expose other values that will be used across the app. For example the userId is used to query the user's companyId - which will also be a member of this controller so that all controllers can inherit it's value. Reason being there are many queries in each controller that will need those values (userId and companyId). So there's a few variables I want to make available in all my controllers, without having to run a query in every controller.

Comment: @Toonsylvania I understand your concern. I added an example.

Comment: I wanted to redirect invalid user groups without putting a isinrole check in every page function.  Addtionally, it is preferred to define the group outside of the code in the appsettings.json file.