# Access custom properties on ApplicationUser class in EF Core 2.0.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am working on a .NET Core application coupled with EF Core 2.0.1 (MySQL via Pomelo).

I have the following in my `ApplicationUser.cs`

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
  public string DisplayUsername { get; set; }
}
```

What is the correct way of accessing that `DisplayUsername` property in my `BaseController.cs`? In .NET Framework, I used to do this in my `BaseController.cs`:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
  public BaseController()
  {
    var prinicpal = (ClaimsPrincipal)Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
    var displayUsername = prinicpal.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.GivenName).Select(c => c.Value).SingleOrDefault();
    ViewBag.DisplayUsername = displayUsername;
  }
}
```

But that doesn't work anymore, because we can no longer do `Thread.CurrentPrinciple`. What is the right way in the latest stable release of .NET Core?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is now a `User` property in controller class (defined in `ControllerBase` class):

```
 // Gets the System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal for user 
 // associated with the executing action.
 public ClaimsPrincipal User { get; }
```

Comment: Thanks @Set, but can you please elaborate? How would I go about accessing the `DisplayUsername` property?

Comment: @Ciwan actually the same way as you did before. Check `User.Claims` and get value from claim with `ClaimTypes.GivenName` type. Alternative  to your code way may be `var name = User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.GivenName)?.Value;`

Comment: Thanks Set, I tried, but I get an error. Apparently, User is `null`. See [screenshot](https://www.screencast.com/t/CiWkSbhIZT).

Comment: @Ciwan this is cause you try to get User in the controller constructor which is called before the `ActionContext` has been set, so you have null values for properties like Context, Request or User. You should do this in action method instead. Check this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33169060/user-getuserid-fails-inside-controllers-constructor)

Comment: I see, so I must create an ActionFilter to make the `DisplayUsername` property available within the ViewBag for all controllers